# Unicode emoji not showing up in tcsh prompt

Tags: freebsd, locale, unicode, tcsh

I set my prompt on tcsh 6.18.01 to use some silly emoji characters, but they don't show up.

```
> cat .cshrc
set prompt = '\n [%~]\n%# '

\360\237\224\245 [~]                                                           
> source .cshrc

\360\237\224\245 [~]                                                           
>
```

I pulled up the special characters window on OSX, found the character I wanted, copied and pasted it into vi on the tcsh machine. It turned up like this `\xf0\x9f\x94\xa5.`

Here's the full uname.

```
FreeBSD raspberry-pi 11.0-CURRENT FreeBSD 11.0-CURRENT #0 r271779: Fri Sep 19 01:18:53 UTC 2014     root@grind.freebsd.org:/usr/obj/arm.armv6/usr/src/sys/RPI-B  arm
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems:

1. your locale should use UTF-8 encoding, but
2. for this platform/configuration/date, that particular character lies outside the ability of tcsh to manage it using the system's wide-character functions.

Using `en_US.UTF-8`, tcsh will show the Unicode value:

```
\U+01F525 [~]
```

For what it's worth, the same happens with the older Debian 7 (from 2013) that I use for a file server.  In discussing [Debian #790847
Fwd: Emoji in lynx](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=790847), Aurélien Jarno noted:

> It happens these emojis are new in Unicode 6.0. glibc 2.21 only has
>   support for Unicode 5.0. This has been fixed in glibc 2.22 which
>   includes support for Unicode 7.0.

[Unicode 6.0](http://unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.0.0/) dates from October 2010, but apparently FreeBSD 11-current in September 2014 did not have the data for that version of Unicode.  FreeBSD 11.0 was just released (in September 2016); its [release notes](https://www.freebsd.org/releases/11.0R/relnotes.html) do not mention an update to the Unicode version.